# how to get an image to display at the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div 100% of the screen height, top of the DIV is a table...Idea being then white space with a image at the bottom of the DIV. When I add the image it appears directly under the table, as opposed to the bottom of the page. How can I fix this? I have tried many things from searching in google...

```
display:block
margin:0 auto;
bototm:0px
```

but no joy, does anyone have any ideas? thanks

Comment: please share code which is used to append image

Comment: You have a typo in the code - bototm:0px. Also you can't have a bottom property without an accompanying position property - e.g position:absolute, position:relative

Comment: @John Try to create [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for other SO users as it will help them to provide you a proper solution.

Comment: Share the code man.. at least something to see

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to parent div then add `position: absolute; bottom:0px;` to the image. This works in most cases but your could be different since you haven't posted the full code. Ps you have a typo `bottom`

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/epEPYw

Comment: And you could also be different by posting it as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I still think this is an acceptable answer as from what John has described this could work

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is one way of doing it: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/BodqBY

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src='...' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I noticed you have a table above the image. This example won't work then. Maybe it's better to go with `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` trick.